# php code to get listbox selected value in variable for where clause

Tags: php, pdo

below is my select tag code..I need to get selected input in temp variable.

and use this variable to search.

FOR EX-

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

**Now I selected Saab from listbox. then get this value in variable in temp
and use this temp variable in search query.**

```
<?php
$temp = "Saab";
$book_no2 = $temp;
$receipt = $database->getRows("SELECT receipt_no FROM scheme_master WHERE book_no2 = :book_no2", array(':book_no2'=>$book_no2));  
?>




<select name="book" onChange="showUser(this.value)">
<?php foreach ($book as $load_book){ ?> 
<option  value=""></option>
    <option  value="<?php echo $load_book["book_no"]; ?>"><?php echo $load_book["book_no"]; ?></option>
<?php }?>
</select>


<?php
$book_no2 = $load_book["book_no"];
$receipt = $database->getRows("SELECT receipt_no FROM scheme_master WHERE book_no2 = :book_no2", array(':book_no2'=>$book_no2));  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should you form and get the selected book from global `$_POST` variable, but make sure you properly escaped all the variables coming from the client side (e.g. using mysql_real_escape_string PHP function).

```
    <?php
    $book_no2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['book']);
    $receipt = $database->getRows("SELECT receipt_no FROM scheme_master WHERE book_no2 = :book_no2", array(':book_no2'=>$book_no2));

?>
<form method="POST">
    <select name="book" onChange="showUser(this.value)">
        <?php foreach ($book as $load_book){ ?>
            <option  value=""></option>
            <option  value="<?php echo $load_book["book_no"]; ?>"<?php if ($load_book["book_no"] == $temp):?> selected="selected"<?php endif?>><?php echo $load_book["book_no"]; ?></option>
        <?php }?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: no i have done this thanks for reply but  i dont need this on button click or any post..

Answer (score 0):

Plz see ...this will resolve my problem....

```
<select  name="book"  onChange="showUser(this.value)">
    <option value="<?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])){ echo $data['book']; }?>"><?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])){echo $data['book'];}?></option> 
    <?php foreach ($book as $load_book){ ?> 
    <option  value=""></option>
        <option  value="<?php echo $load_book["book_no"]; ?>"><?php echo $load_book["book_no"]; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
    </select>

    <?php
    $book_no2 = $load_book["book_no"];
    $receipt = $database->getRows("SELECT DISTINCT receipt_no FROM scheme_master WHERE book_no2 = :book_no2", array(':book_no2'=>$book_no2));  
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your first file

```
<form action="second page" method="post"
 <select name="car">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</    option>
 </select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then pass this to your temp var

```
$temp=$_POST[`car`];
```